# Requested URL not found on the server in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, http-status-code-404

I was working on XAMPP when I encountered this. 
My code was intended to take some information as input from the user via a form. 
Then show the output in the same page after the "SUBMIT" button has been pressed.
(I used " method="POST"> in the HTML part of the code...)

> **Object not found!**
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the [referring  page](http://localhost/lerningphp/myprojectpage.php) seems to be wrong or outdated. 
>       Please inform the author of [that page](http://localhost/learningphp/myprojectpage.php) about the error. 
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> **Error 404** 
>   localhost Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.4

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The answer is pretty straighforward ... you're sending the request to a page that doesn't exists.

Check your error.log and access.log of apache, and you'll see the page that you're tryingto reach. Change your form "action" to an existing page.

Comment: Can you post the code of your html form?

Comment: Please post the form tag at least, so we can help you

Comment: <html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?> method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Username  </td> <td><input type="text" name="username" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email </td> <td><input type="text" name="email" ></td></tr>

<tr><td>Password  </td> <td><input type="password" name="password" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Comment   </td> <td><input type="text" name="comment" ></td></tr>
<tr> <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" ></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: And, This is the PHP code 
  <?php  
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $em    = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
    $com  = $_POST["comment"];
        
    echo "NAME     : ".$user."<br>";
    echo "EMAIL    : ".$em."<br>";
    echo "PASSWORD : ".$pass."<br>";
    echo "COMMENT  : ".$com."<br>";
   }
     ?>

Comment: Missing  a doublequote after ?> -> <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">

Comment: @Dieter OH DAMN! THAT'S RIGHT !!... Didn't notice that. Thanks a lot sir. Now it's working :D

Comment: @YealTakian Thats cool. Please mark my answer as correct ;-) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending the form to a page that doesn't exist. Make sure you use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in the action attribute of your form.
Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```